# Can't customize TimePicker colors

Tags: android, android-view, android-custom-view, android-timepicker

I am trying to get my time picker to look like this:
[The desired outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwDOm.png)

So I am doing what I found on [This guide](http://www.zoftino.com/android-timepicker-example)

And this is what I actually get:[The true outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDVMw.png)

This is my custom style:

```
<style name="customTimePicker" parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.TimePicker">
    <item name="android:timePickerMode">clock</item>
    <item name="android:headerBackground">#0076a3</item>
    <item name="android:numbersTextColor">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:numbersInnerTextColor">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:numbersSelectorColor">#fbc014</item>
    <item name="android:numbersBackgroundColor">#004a80</item>
    <item name="android:amPmTextColor">#ffffff</item>
</style>
```

And this is how I use it in my XML file:

```
<TimePicker
    android:id="@+id/tpAnalog"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/customTimePicker"
    style="@style/customTimePicker"
    android:visibility="visible"/>
```

On the preview screen on the android studio, it looks almost like I want [preview on Android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrDED.png)

So why when I ran it on my device this is not working?

**Edit**: I forgot to use this line of code on my activity theme:

```
<item name="android:timePickerStyle">@style/customTimePicker</item>
```

It seems to solve all my issues except that I still can't change the text color of the selected number. [This is the text I want to change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPbGY.png).  Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

[image: o change DatePicker colors (calendar mode) at application level define below properties.]

```
<style name="MyAppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
<item name="colorAccent">#ff6d00</item>
<item name="colorControlActivated">#33691e</item>
<item name="android:selectableItemBackgroundBorderless">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
<item name="colorControlHighlight">#d50000</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this style it's work for me for the change background color.

```
  <style name="MyTimePickerWidgetStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.TimePicker">
            <item name="android:headerBackground">#0076A3</item>
            <item name="android:numbersTextColor">#b71c1c</item>
            <item name="android:numbersInnerTextColor">#f44336</item>
            <item name="android:numbersSelectorColor">#DCA811</item>
            <item name="android:numbersBackgroundColor">#004A80</item>
            <item name="android:amPmTextColor">#fff</item>
        </style>
        <TimePicker
        android:id="@+id/timePicker"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#359EF3"
        android:theme="@style/MyTimePickerWidgetStyle"
        style="@style/MyTimePickerWidgetStyle" />
```

[image]